# Dynamic creation of ASP Calendar controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, calendar

Based on the data being returned from a database, a number of textboxes and checkboxes are dynamically added to my page using the following code:

```
int counter = 0;

foreach (DataRow dr in dsData.Tables[0].Rows){
    CheckBox chk_valid = new CheckBox();
    chk_valid.Enabled = true;
    chk_valid.ID = "dynamicchk" + counter.ToString();

    TextBox txt_task = new TextBox();
    txt_task.Enabled = true;
    txt_task.Text = dr[0].ToString();
    txt_task.Width = 300;
    txt_task.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
    txt_task.ID = "dynamictask" + counter.ToString();

    TextBox txt_id = new TextBox();
    txt_id.Enabled = true;
    txt_id.Text = "ID.";
    txt_id.Width = 90;
    txt_id.ID = "dynamicid" + counter.ToString();

    TextBox txt_email = new TextBox();
    txt_email.Enabled = true;
    txt_email.Text = "E-mail Address";
    txt_email.Width = 150;
    txt_email.ID = "dynamicemail" + counter.ToString();

    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(chk_valid);
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(txt_task);
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(txt_id);
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(txt_email);
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br />"));

    counter += 1;
}
```

Now, I also need to dynamically add calendar controls (there should be a button in front of the textbox and checkbox in each row; and on clicking that button, a calendar should be displayed. On selecting a date from the calendar, the textbox value should be changed to the date selected.)

Normally, this would've been easy if I were to use jQuery UI but my limitation is that in the environment I work in, I cannot use jQuery UI or any other ajax calendar. I **have** to use asp:calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you should design the calendar, textbox, button etc functionality inside a user control. Then in your loop, you just add that control into your dynamic controls with a simple LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx") call.

To go one step further, you should consider using the asp:Repeater control. It does everything that you are doing manually right now: looping through data and creating dynamic controls. It would take less effort to do that since you could actually design the rows as a template with the ASPX designer, instead of writing lots of code.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this out. But tell me, suppose I include a checkbox, a textbox, and a calendar control in my custom user control. And say I put ten of these custom controls on my page.  Will I be able to refer to individual checkboxes of each control? How will I be able to do that??

Comment: You have to design your user control properly, according to OOP principles. The user control will access its own nested controls (checkbox, textbox, etc), but the outside world will not. Your user control should expose easy-to-handle properties for the outside world. Look at the Textbox control for example: you don't know what it does on the inside (create an <input> element, etc), but you can easily access it's Text property.

Comment: I want to find out if the checkboxes are checked or not. Will that be possible with several custom user controls?

Comment: You can expose a property inside your user control: public bool IsChecked { get { return checkbox1.Checked; } } This way, the outside world can easily access this property, while inside your control, you can easily access checkbox1 or whatever it's name, because you made this control in the designer.